# Tomcat6 - how to get session parameters via log4j OR JULI?

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j

I am facing an issue where a deployed web application (without source code or any references) seems having a problem with some session parameters. I don't know how to reverse-engineering that application so I have a feeling that the only way I could show this incident is to use either log4j OR tomcat's own JULI tool to get a list of session parameters. I have a read about Wrox's Professional Apache Tomcat 6 and to be frank it doesn't help too much in this regard...

Any hint on which direction to go with log4j or JULI?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter to print a list of session attributes to Log4J like this:

```
public class SessionAttributesLoggingFilter implements Filter {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();

            Enumeration<String> sessionAttributeNames = session.getAttributeNames();
            log.info("Session attributes before request ----------------------->");
            while (sessionAttributeNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                String attr = sessionAttributeNames.nextElement();
                log.info(" "+attr + " = " + session.getAttribute(attr));
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            sessionAttributeNames = session.getAttributeNames();
            log.info("Session attributes after request ----------------------->");
            while (sessionAttributeNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                String attr = sessionAttributeNames.nextElement();
                log.info(" "+attr + " = " + session.getAttribute(attr));
            }
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        log.info("Logging session attributes ...");
    }

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Than add the mapping to your web.xml and restart your app:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>sessionLogging</filter-name>
    <filter-class>PACKAGENAME.SessionAttributesLoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sessionLogging</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```